# Is there a way to both redirect and send json in express?

Tags: json, angularjs, express

I have a registration functionality that sends a confirmation email to a user in my application, and I want to do something similar to the following:

```
return res.status(200).redirect('/').json({
  message: 'Successfully confirmed your account!'
});
```

I knew this wouldn't work, but I think it demonstrates what I want. I am using AngularJS, which is why I need to render JSON to the client. How could I best accomplish this?

Comment: If you're using AngularJS, why not make the HTTP request via JS and just return JSON normally?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean. I am making the HTTP request to the server through the registration page. This is my server code handling the confirmation route that is generated from the user id, sent in email. When a user clicks on the link, the route adds a confirmed field to their document in the database, and then redirects back into the Angular application. (E.g.: confirm/:id, -> /home)

Comment: Ah, alright. I didn't read your question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to have the browser somehow forward response body data across a request. There are however multiple ways to achieve what you're trying to do:

1. Simplest way: just send the message as a query string argument. This of course enables anybody to craft URLs with messages, so you might want to validate or just pass a key and look up the message based on that.
2. Use a session and put the message in there. Delete it after it's been shown. These are usually called "flash messages".
3. You could also set a flag in your database for this, but it seems a bit overkill to have an entire field just to show a message.